# got a select that does 10 query in doctrine (Symfony)

Tags: mysql, symfony1, doctrine

I got a big query that execute 11 query, I didnt know where the problem is, but found the problem was in a select a did for geo loc, anyone has an idea how to correct that?

It happens only when i use this query SfDoctrinePaginate

Investigating further $q->select("a.longitude") create as much queries..

The problem:

```
$q->select("a.longitude, a.latitude, (3959 * acos(cos(radians('".$lat."')) * cos(radians(latitude)) * cos(radians(longitude) - radians('".$long."')) + sin(radians('".$lat."')) * sin(radians(latitude)))) AS distance");
```

the complete model:

```
public function getListItems($orderby, $budget, $motscles, $userid, $catID, $useDistance = false)
{
     $useDistance = true;
   // CHANGE ORDER 
   if(!$orderby){
     $orderby = "a.created_at DESC";
   }else if($orderby == "price"){
     $orderby = "a.price ASC";
   }else if($orderby == "date") {
     $orderby = "a.created_at DESC";
    }else{
     $orderby = "a.created_at DESC";
   }

   // Search Keywords in table
   if($motscles){
    $searchItem = Doctrine_Core::getTable('csw_Article');
    $results = $searchItem->search($motscles);
    $ids = array();

    foreach ($results as $result) {

        $ids[] = $result['id'];
    }
    if(sizeof($ids) == 0){
      $ids[] = 0;
    }
   }        
    $q = Doctrine_Core::getTable('csw_Article')
        ->createQuery("a")
        ->leftJoin('a.csw_CategorieArticle ca');

    $sfContext = sfContext::getInstance()->getUser();

    if($useDistance){

        $lat = (string)($sfContext->getAttribute('userLat')) ? $sfContext->getAttribute('userLat') : sfConfig::get("app_user_lat");
       $long = (string)($sfContext->getAttribute('userLong')) ? $sfContext->getAttribute('userLong') : sfConfig::get("app_user_long");  
        $radius = 18;
        $q->select("a.longitude, a.latitude, (3959 * acos(cos(radians('".$lat."')) * cos(radians(latitude)) * cos(radians(longitude) - radians('".$long."')) + sin(radians('".$lat."')) * sin(radians(latitude)))) AS distance");
        $q->having("distance < ?", $radius);
    }
    if($orderby == "distance") {            
        $q->orderBy("distance desc");   
    }               
        $q->addOrderBy($orderby);

     if($catID){
       $q->where('ca.categorie_id = ?', $catID);
     }
     if($budget != 0){

      $budget_min = $budget - ($budget * 0.20);
      $budget_max = $budget + ($budget * 0.20);
      $q->addwhere('a.price > ?',$budget_min)
        ->addwhere('a.price < ?',$budget_max);
     }  
     if($userid){
       $q->WhereIn('a.userid = ?', $userid);
     }


     if($motscles){
       $q->whereIn('a.id', $ids);

     }        
     $q->execute();      
     return $q;
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Symfony 1.4 makes 15 DB requests for 1 query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072223/symfony-1-4-makes-15-db-requests-for-1-query). Do not create multiple questions for the same problem.

Comment: I flagged the other question to be deleted, the other question was not relevant to the problem, unless I changed all the question

Comment: Is there a reason youre not usin the [geographical behavior](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/behaviors%3Acore-behaviors%3Ageographical/en)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change all **where** by **whereIn** like:

```
if($userid){
    $q->andWhereIn('a.userid', $userid);
}

if($catID){
    $q->andWhereIn('ca.categorie_id', $catID);
}
```

I think this happens because when you're using the results in the view the paginator cant fetch all records in a row, so for each item has to do the query to get all fields.

Answer (score 0):

I am really not sure why but here what was the problem:

I used
select('a.latitude')

when I should have used...

select('a.*')

Comment: IF you only pick specific columns then that will be the data loaded... the rest of the data will not be loaded until you call the accessor for its corresponding property... see [lazy loading fileds](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_0/hu/working-with-models:fetching-objects:field-lazy-loading)